# Can someone please explain this answer regarding reference variables?

Tags: variables, object, reference

The task was...

Suppose  a reference variable  of type  String  called myString has already  been declared . Create an object  of type  String  and assign  it to the reference variable  myString.

The correct answer is...

```
    String myString2 = new String();
    myString = myString2;
```

I don't get it though.  It just says create an object and assign it to the reference variable.  How are you supposed to know to call it myString2, and why create it if is equal to the first one?  What exactly is this doing?  If myString is already an object, is it essentially creating an object of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking but I am going to try to explain it the way I have understood.

So when you first do String `String myString = newString();`, it is creating a string variable in the memory. Then what myString actually does is to point to the position of that memory.

So when you go `String myString2 = new String();` You are doing exactly the same thing except at different position in the memory. Then when you go `myString = myString2;` you are making the `myString` reference to equal to `myString2` reference, hence making them point to the same position in the memory - having the same reference value.

I hope that was what you were asking

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you would do that though?  What's the purpose of creating something with the exact same reference value?  Isn't that redundant?

Comment: Right now? yes. but maybe the assignment was just trying to teach you how references work. I can't think on top of my head exact situation where I would want two different variables pointing to exactly the same reference. Maybe when you want to mutate them differently.